# How to share Firestore documents from one sub-collection to another while keeping the access rights intact?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

This is how my Firestore DB is structured

[image: This is how my Firestore DB is structured]

For example, now I want `userA` to share the `Recipe2` with `userB`.

I want to list the `Recipe2` in `UserB` UI as well when I fetch his/her recipes.
The way I am fetching the recipes in my Swift code is that a user can only view his/her docs or collections, i.e. `userB` can never query/read the `userA's` recipes.
Keeping in view that I might allow userB to modify shared recipes in future, how can I achieve sharing feature? I don't want to create multiple copies, my Firestore rules are set to not allow any user to read other user's data, with all this what is best possible solution?

Comment: Why are you averse to duplicating records? Denormalization is NoSQL standard operating procedure. For a scalable solution, you have to either grant users access rights of users’ data (which can and should be limited) or denormalize the recipes.

Comment: how can I grant access rights to userB to read recipes of userA? I want to know on what level I have to manage these rights? On FB rules or inside my code?

Comment: If you're okay with denormalizing your data and allowing for copies of recipes to exist in the database, which is how NoSQL is designed to work, I can recommend an architecture. Otherwise, refer to this link for granular security rules: https://fireship.io/snippets/firestore-rules-recipes/

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ways to do it handle this, and providing the best possible solution would be impossible without understanding the entire use case.

Let me suggest this:

When you have a situation where there's my data, your data and OUR data, it's often best to put OUR data in a separate collection, using uid's and rules to determine who can access what data. For example

```
users
   UserA
      ...
   UserB
      ...
recipes
   recipe0
      owner: UserA
      name: "pasta fazul"
      ingredients
         ...
      visible_to
         UserB
```

Then a rule that would allow a user to read recipes where their uid is listed in visible_to, and only the owner matching the owner uid can make changes.

Comment: Is `visible_to` a subcollection or an array?

Comment: @liquid There are a number of options; you could use and array or a map or a number of other options. Array would be nice because you could then leverage .arrayContains for queries and the such - like if you wanted to know which recipes a certain user has access to.

Comment: The problem with an array is that it doesn't scale well with a growing userbase because of document size limits. And the problem with a subcollection is the difficulty of querying.

Comment: @liquid I would not suggest a sub-collection for this use case - although it could be made to work. Keep in mind that scalability is relative and the big picture is you have a document that is storing an array of index's and uid's which is a *tiny amount of information*. There is very little about Firebase that doesn't scale, if anything, so It would be no problem handling *thousands* of users in each recipe.

Comment: An array could handle thousands of users but not more. It couldn’t handle a million users. And it should be able to. The only two scalable solutions are modifying access rights or denormalizing the recipes.

Comment: Thank you Jay. I think I’m going to give a try to the solution you have suggested but I want to be clear about visible_to, I might be sharing recipes with 20 or 30 or may be 100 users in future, so how should I proceed?

Comment: @liquid The limit is not the number of users, but the amount of data. A single document limit is 1Mb (1 million bytes). If an array element containing a user takes up approximately 100 bytes (index + uid + overhead), then it would hold approximately  10,000 users. If you have 10,000 users observing your recipe, then congratulations! That being said, there are a number of other options if you really have more then 10,000 users.

Comment: @Feteh if you have a couple hundred users an array would work well for this use case. It should be very simple to code up. Give that a try with a test case and if it doesn't work like you want you can explore other options; like creating a recipe collection where each document contains has a user id and recipe reference field. Then you could essentially have unlimited documents. But again - as usual with NoSQL databases, your structure if dependent on the queries you want to run against it and without understanding the entire use case, it would be difficult to be too specific.

Comment: There are two problems with your thinking. The first is that you've picked an arbitrary number of 10k users sharing a single recipe as good enough. Why not 15k or 100k? If the app had a large-enough userbase with a popular-enough recipe then your data architecture would break the app because it's not designed to scale. Always design to scale. The second problem is your disregard for the nature of Firestore and how it's designed to be used. Nevermind that the OP will incur tremendous ingress/egress costs from giant documents, Firestore is specifically built for large numbers of small documents.

Comment: @liquid Not an arbitrary number; please see the **math** in the comment. Also as mentioned, there are other approaches but we would need to understand the use case to address it. *disregard for the nature of Firestore* Well that's not accurate at all, lol. You may have Firestore mixed up with another service because the billing is for **document reads**, not reading giant documents. See [Billing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#pricing_overview). While there is a charge for space, that would be consumed regardless of HOW the user id's are stored. Array is fine for this case.

Comment: @liquid Oh, and you may want to check the Firestore documentation as *large numbers of small documents* isn't accurate at all. **Cloud Firestore is optimized for storing large collections of small documents** which is totally different. Check out the documentation for [Cloud Firestore Data model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model). If you have a specific question and example, please post it so myself and the Firebasers can take a look and provide a possible solution.

Comment: 10k is a completely arbitrary number of users to be able to share a recipe because you think it's big enough to cover his userbase which you presume is and will remain small and small enough to not break the app. And the nature of Firestore, as it is even documented, is large numbers of small documents. Your approach goes against a core Firestore best practice. Furthermore, Firestore bills users for more than just document reads and writes, it also bills users for ingress and egress--which is the amount of data passed through the network. 1MB documents all over the place will not be cheap.

Comment: @liquid lol. Ok. If you have an constructive answer to this users question, please post it!

Comment: When I said Firestore is designed for "large numbers of small documents", what did you think I meant? Documents can only be contained in collections. Therefore, "large numbers of small documents" precisely means large collections of small-sized documents. There could be no other intepretation.

Comment: @liquid I believe you very clearly demonstrated what I was saying. Firestore limits document size to 1Mb, which is what is considered a Small Document. If the data is 1Mb is size, then it's small, which coincides with the math I presented above, which *could* store the number of users the OP was asking about. If the OP is expecting more then there are other options. Please present your answer to help the OP and future readers.

Comment: My point is that I don’t think a million bytes is considered a small document. I would even say that a million-byte document is not only large but obese.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in the comments, you must either grant users access to each other's documents or denormalize the documents themselves. Denormalizing data in NoSQL is not only standard operating procedure but a highly-effective optimization tool and one that should be used when needed.

Firstly, Firestore documents cannot be larger than 1 MB which means that with a relatively small userbase you can opt for a different architecture (that would save you money on reads and writes). However, I would advise against architecting data that doesn't scale with the userbase because userbase size can be the most difficult metric to predict. This solution can scale with a userbase of practically any size. Secondly, this solution is designed so that when the owner of a recipe modifies that recipe, their shared instances can easily be found and also be updated (if needed). Thirdly, this solution is designed so that when a user who is displaying a shared recipe modifies that recipe, the original author can easily be found and that recipe can be updated or notated (if needed). Finally, this solution makes displaying a user's recipes (that the user both owns and borrows) possible with just two simple queries that don't require accessing another user's data.

```
[collection]
    <document>

[users]
    <userA>
        [my-recipes]
            <recipe1>
            <recipe2>
            <recipe3>
                [sharing-with]
                    <userB> (acts as a bookmark with the user's info)

    <userB>
        [my-recipes]
            <recipe4>
            <recipe5>
            <recipe6>
        [shared-recipes]
            <recipe3> (contains an owner field)
```

Comment: I will present this incredible solution to my team, the catch here is we need two queries to update a recipe and two queries to read recipes. Thank you for the great solution!